# Vue js add external scripts files to my app

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

**I have downloaded some HTML template that comes with custom js files and jquery. I had to attach those js to my app. and continue with Vue.**

**I tried many ways to add the them but still have error:**

[image]
The folders in my projects :

[image]

The ways i tried :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**I can not find the problem!**

Comment: Save yourself some headache - when using Vue, do not mix anything based on jQuery. There are lots of of good Vue native components for almost anything....

Comment: There is a package available. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put this scripts not to src but to public folder and use static path `'static/content/...'` or `'public/content/...'` or better `process.env.PUBLIC_URL + 'content/...'` depends on your build config.

Comment: I move the js file to frontend/app/public
and  i call it as:
        <script type="application/javascript" defer src="./../public/js/vendor/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
but is still not seen
@ishaba

Comment: You don't need ./../ in src. Check this https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder there should be an answer for you

Comment: loadScirpt(process.env.BASE_URL+'content/...') – should work

Comment: No need to define it manually. What is result when you try? loadScirpt(process.env.BASE_URL+'content/...') or <script  src="<%= BASE_URL %>js/vendor/owl.carousel.min.js">?

Comment: Its work, thank you, but the scripts load asynchronously, i will add them in promise function.

Comment: I have another problem as i loaded the scripts in the index page, when i change the router to another component and return back to the index page, the scripts will not loaded (their effects not found) although i loaded them in App.vue
@ishaba

Answer (score 1):

You want to `import` the module like any other. See package documentation:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-owl-carousel2

**Installation**

```sh
npm i -s vue-owl-carousel2
```

or

```sh
yarn add vue-owl-carousel2
```

**Usage**

```js
import carousel from 'vue-owl-carousel2'

export default {
    components: { carousel },
}
```

**Basic Usage**

```html
<carousel>

    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?1">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?2">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?3">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?4">

</carousel>
```

Comment: The package was last updated 2 years ago and github repo link is broken. I would avoid using something like that...

Comment: The carousel  is just one of many files :( 
@Peter Krebs

Comment: The package is almost that old in general with a newer version teased. If it is not available as a package the OP should use another.

Comment: Okay then follow the advice of @ishaba